# X Server crashes when I try to change settings in Eclipse on remote Linux node

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, xserver

I've written a C++ application in windows, and want to be able to run it on a Linux cluster node without using Wine. I therefore tried to connect to a cluster node (with an X Server running) and once connected tried to compile the code in Eclipse (C++). However, when I try to set up the linking in the Eclipse menu, the program crashes and I get a `'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'` X Server error.

I found this bug report
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333227

And tried to use `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` but it made no difference.

What else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an easy solution; I switched to Cygwin/X instead of the X server software I used before. Not a crash in sight.